# Unsure why value becomes undefined in listener event for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, undefined, infowindow

I am trying to get a string from an array of arrays. I want to get the first property [0] into an info window. I am able to use the second and third values to set the placement of markers and I am also able to console.log the first value.

The particular JavaScript code is here:

```
markers = [
["4841 Bethesda Avenue (Elm Street)", 38.980724, -77.0964],
["7171 Woodmont Avenue", 38.980097, -77.093662],
["921 Wayne Avenue", 38.995740, -77.025652],
["801 Ellsworth Drive",38.997778, -77.025071]
];

infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    console.log("markers: " + markers[i][0]);
    position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position, 
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
    console.log("markers 2: " + markers[i][0]);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent("<div>Hello, World" + markers[i][0] + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
};
```

When I `console.log(markers[i][0])` it produces what I want. However, once it enters the `addListener` event, it loses it and I am not sure why.

Why does it become undefined?

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kb9v4fe5/4/)

HTML:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Parking Garage Availability</h1>

<div id="map"></div>

<ul id="list"></ul>
<p id="GAR57"></p>
<p id="GAR31"></p>
<p id="GAR60"></p>
<p id="GAR61"></p>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var map;
var mapProp;
var marker;
var markers;
var url;
var myData;
var time;
var available;
var total;
var facility;
var position;
var infoWindow;

function initialize() {
    mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.994890, -77.063416),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    initialize();
    url = 'https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/qahs-fevu.json';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        myData = data;
        for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
            time = (myData[i].asofdatetime).slice(11);
            available = myData[i].space_count;
            total = myData[i].total_spaces;
            facility = myData[i].facilitynumber;
            if (facility === "GAR 57") {
                facility = "4841 Bethesda Avenue (Elm Street)";
                $('#GAR57').html('As of ' + time + ' there are ' + available +
                    ' of ' + total + ' at ' + facility);
            } else if (facility === "GAR 31") {
                facility = "7171 Woodmont Avenue";
                $('#GAR31').html('As of ' + time + ' there are ' + available +
                    ' of ' + total + ' at ' + facility);
            } else if (facility === "GAR 60") {
                facility = "921 Wayne Avenue";
                $('#GAR60').html('As of ' + time + ' there are ' + available +
                    ' of ' + total + ' at ' + facility);
            } else {
                facility = "801 Ellsworth Drive";
                $('#GAR61').html('As of ' + time + ' there are ' + available +
                    ' of ' + total + ' at ' + facility);
            }
        }
    });
    //set markers
    markers = [
        ["4841 Bethesda Avenue (Elm Street)", 38.980724, -77.0964],
        ["7171 Woodmont Avenue", 38.980097, -77.093662],
        ["921 Wayne Avenue", 38.995740, -77.025652],
        ["801 Ellsworth Drive", 38.997778, -77.025071]
    ];
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        console.log("markers: " + markers[i][0]);
        position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            title: markers[i][0]
        });
        console.log("markers 2: " + markers[i][0]);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent("<div>Hello, World" + markers[i][0] + "</div>");
            infoWindow.open(map, this);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kb9v4fe5/5/) using code function closure as in [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: @geocodezip what is `(marker, i)` doing at the end of the function?

Comment: Those are the parameters to the anonymous function that returns the click listener function (` (function (marker, i) { return function () { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Markers[i][0] becomes undefined because it does not exist in the scope of the function within addListener i.e. you're not passing *markers* into the function.

Instead, you're passing in *marker*

```
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    console.log("markers: " + markers[i][0]);
    position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position, 
        map: map,
        title: markers[i][0]
    });
    console.log("markers 2: " + marker.title);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setContent("<div>Hello, World " + marker.title + "</div>");
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
};
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/sdn23obr/) shows an example displaying the title when the marker is clicked. Which I'm assuming is what you wanted to achieve.